# Looking to pass dynamic data as jsonpath request

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

```
 @Test
public void basicAuthLogin() {
    //language=JSON
    String jsonBody = "{\n" +
            "  \"name\": \"Foo\"\n" +
            "}";

    given().auth().preemptive().basic(username, password)
            .body(jsonBody)
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .when()
            .post("http://localhost:8080/secured/hello")
            .then()
            .statusCode(200);
}
```

I wanted to pass dynamic data for name instead of "Foo". How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `DataProvider` here. Which actually provides data to your test case in the runtime. There are multiple ways to provide dynamic data to the test case before, after, and during the test case.

- Use `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)` in case if you are using `JUnit` and you can provide data with `@Parameters`
- Use `@DataProvider (name = “name_of_dataprovider”)` and create data-provider method in case if you are using `TestNG` and you can add property `@Test (dataProvider = "data-provider")` in your testCase.
- You can provide input from a file, you can write generic mapper with the help of `objectMapper` or `Jackson` lib fetch data and convert into the object at runtime and use it as an input parameter.

Comment: FYI Jackson is a part of Rest-Assured dependency

Comment: sure. I added dataprovider to pass data for name, for example NameValue has 3 sets of data - "school", "college","university". While passing name, using $NameValue throws error. How do I fix errors here?